# how to use npm to install all node modules in local network?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, offline

My node app will deploy in a bank that can't access the internet. Can I download all the node modules in a local directory, and install them from it, or just copy the node_modules to the bank machines? Any safe and practical advise will be highly appreciated, thank you.

**OR** 
How to add `node_modules` dependencies without using **internet** .

Answer (score 2):

Add offline-npm to your project to serve a npm compatible tgz file wich contains all dependencies for offline installation with npm install.

Additionally you can use offline-npm -n to install packages from your local npm cache directory

For **installation**

```
npm install -g offline-npm
```

**Usage**

1) Open terminal and go to your project you want to prepare for offline use. This folder needs to contain a `package.json` file.

2) Prepare your project for offline use

```
offline-npm --add
```

3) This changes the package.json file and adds a offline folder which will contain all your dependencies.

Pack your project

```
npm pack
```

For more details , visit the [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-npm)

Hope this answer gets useful to you .

Comment: Thank you~I have solved my problem using yarn offline.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you will want to bundle your `node_modules` into your deployable artifact.

There are some gotchas here around any native dependencies as you need to match the nodejs version of the build environment with the target system.

The easiest way to achieve this in my experience is by using docker to build and package your deployment. Though it is possible to do when running directly on host machines, you may find it safest to just avoid the usage of native dependencies to remove any risk of things breaking from a nodejs or os update.

I've also successfully achieved this packaging the nodejs binary into my deployment artifact that was deployed directly on centos hosts, however we had a mixture of centos 6 and centos 7 hosts at the time, which brought additional complexity related to different glibc versions causing nodejs to fail to start with the system provided library.

In short if you can I would use docker to package your application into a completely self contained image.

Comment: Docer is good choice, but we always don't have the root privileges in bank, we can't install docer. If we can keep the node version intact, is it a good way to  use offline node module by copy node_modules directory?

Comment: Yeah so basically if docker isn't an option I would include the node_modules in your deployment artifact, presumably a tar ball / zip file, and ensure that the same operating system and nodejs version is used by your ci boxes as your production boxes.

Answer (score 1):

you can just copy the node_modules into the deployment machine but it is bad practice.

there are other solutions like using `local-npm` package... your npm installs are fetched from the registry and then modules and their dependencies get stored in a local PouchDB database. This caches them so subsequent npm installs use the local cache rather than calling to the network. local-npm also takes care of keeping modules updated when they change. It does this by listening for changes to the remote registry so you don't have to worry about staleness.

or bundling your packages to use them offline you could visit this link for more details for offline installation of npm packages:
https://addyosmani.com/blog/using-npm-offline/

Answer (score 1):

## How to install node modules in local network?

### 1. Solution: yarn offline and 'Offline Mirro'

One of the main advantages of Yarn is that it can install node_modules from files located in file system. We call it “Offline Mirror” because it mirrors the files downloaded from registry during the first build and stores them locally for future builds.

### 2. New problem: How to use yarn in local network?

Download [yarn.tar.gz](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases) into the local repository, and install it in local node_modules directory.

```
npm install yarn.tar.gz --no-save
```

### 3. Usage

# run `yarn install`, and download the node modules (.tar.gz) into the offline mirror directory '$REPOSITORY/yarn/yarn-offline-mirror'.

```
npm run online-install
```

# with yarn.lock file, install node_modules from offline mirror directory '$REPOSITORY/yarn/yarn-offline-mirror'

```
npm run offline-install
```

### 4. Problems

#### 4.1. problem 1

4.1.1. description

error can`t make a request in offline mode("http://....")

4.1.2. reason

the indirect dependencies could not be downloaded into offline mirror directory

4.1.3. resolution

```
yarn config set yarn-offline-mirror-pruning false
```

### 5. Github demo

[yarn-offline-deploy-demo](https://github.com/momopig/yarn-offline-deploy-demo)

### 6. Reference

[1. Running Yarn offline](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/offline-mirror/)