# how to install npm packages that are stored in my pc while offline

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install npm packages that are stored in my network drive in seperate files , I tried to create a node modules file and put the npm packages in there and then run this line for example :

```
npm install --save path
```

but i'm getting npm ERR not found and no network connection .

So how do i install them?

thanks

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57752923/how-to-use-npm-to-install-all-node-modules-in-local-network